# Get facebook user profile info by javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get person's basic profile information (name, email, likes, cover picture, etc). For this I'm implementing as stated on facebook developer docs as given below.

```js
function getUserData() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,age_range,link,gender,picture', 
        function(response) {
        console.info(response);
    }); 
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: [App Id],
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.6',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    //check user session and refresh it
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
    //user is authorized
    getUserData();
            } else {
    //user is not authorized
    }
     }); 
};

(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
         return;
     }
     js = d.createElement(s);
     js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbPermission = function(){
     FB.login(function(response) {
         if (response.authResponse) {
     getUserData();
          }
     }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
};
```

But it is not working. Following cases are occuring.

1) When a user is not logged into facebook, facebook's login dialogue box appears.

When Logged in then, facebook's permission dialogue box appears stating xxx will receive your xxx details. After clicking on continue as username, nothing happens. There are no details in response.

2) When a user logged in facebook neither facebook's permission dialogue box appears nor details are received in response.

How do I get required details?

Comment: FB.login must be called on user interaction, why do you call it on page load?

Comment: read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Actually FB.login is already in function which is onclick event on a button. I mistakenly mentioned above it as called onload.

Comment: ok, then fix the code so it looks like YOUR code, this is confusing ;)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code as I have implemented. It is working now.
I also need page info (likes, etc) of a profile if any. How can I get that?

Comment: did you check out the api reference already? you can find all the information you need in there, including example code.

Comment: Yes I checked the mentioned reference, but didn't found anything to get Facebook PAGE info (likes, followers). I need to get particular Facebook PAGE  (not Facebook profile) details also. Can you please mention where it is there in the mentioned reference if it is or how can I get those details?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: Yes already gone through above link. But it needs Page ID in the request. How can I get Page ID (s) of the Pages of a particular account if any?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/

Comment: Thanks. But now the issue is that when I'm hitting the API - "me/accounts" in Facebook Graph API Explorer tool, I'm getting the response, but when using same API in my application I'm getting empty response. Does it require any permossion to fetch the details?
I'm using the API as -
FB.api("/me/accounts",function (response) {
       if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response);
       }
     });

Comment: of course it does, did you not read the api reference? all the permissions you need are in there. you really need to get familiar with the api reference, you are pretty much asking for every single step here... ;)

Comment: OK. Got it. Given all the permissions required and still not working. I guess the reason is that some of those permissions require Facebook review for the app.

Comment: no, please read about login review in the docs too. you can use all permissions as user with a role in the app. make sure you actually get asked for the permission.

Comment: Ok, I am testing this with the Facebook account which is added in the development role in the app. But still getting empty response for  accounts api. Given the permissions - ads_management, manage_pages, pages_show_list as required. What could be wrong?

Comment: Also after login with facebook dialogue box in the app, it is showing blank facebook popup and the callback of fb.login is not executing. What can be the issue?

Comment: manage_pages is the only relevant permission to get pages you manage. make sure you get ask for that permission, debug the access token, make sure you actually manage pages with that user.

Comment: Thanks but the issue I posted previously is totally different. Submitting app for review for permissions. Till then I'm calling FB.api with basic permissions - email & public_profile only inside FB.login. The issue is that FB.login prompts for login with facebook login dialogue box properly but after clicking on login button there, the login popup turns blank and also the success callback of FB.login is not executing.